# how to filter rows based on unix based regular expressions passed as an input argument to a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

csvFile = "csv.csv"
csvDelim = '@@@'
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, engine="python", index_col=False, delimiter= csvDelim)
df.head()


ID  col_1   
0   ACLKB
1   CLKAA
2   AACLK
3   BBBCLK
```

The regular expression to be passed is *CLK* and the column name is 'col_1'

```
text = '*CLK*'
findtext = 'r'+text+".*"
colName = 'Signal'

df[colName].str.match(text)
```

I am getting the following results which are incorrect.

```
 0     False
 1     False
 2     False
 3     False
 4     False
The expected output is  
 0     True
 1     True
 2     True
 3     True
 4     True

 Can someone help me to filter rows based on regular expression passed as above  
         error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-110-8d1c1b6b2d15> in <module>()
     ----> 1 df['Signal'].str.match(findtext)

              ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in match(self, pat, case, flags, na, as_indexer)
              1571     def match(self, pat, case=True, flags=0, na=np.nan, as_indexer=None):
              1572         result = str_match(self._data, pat, case=case, flags=flags, na=na,
        ->    1573                            as_indexer=as_indexer)
              1574         return self._wrap_result(result)
               1575 

            ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in str_match(arr, pat, case, flags, na, as_indexer)
       495         flags |= re.IGNORECASE
       496 
    --> 497     regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
      498 
      499     if (as_indexer is False) and (regex.groups > 0):

     ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\re.py in compile(pattern, flags)
     231 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
     232     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
  --> 233     return _compile(pattern, flags)
     234 
     235 def purge():

  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
   299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
   300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
```

--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
       302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
       303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

```
 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
   560     if isstring(p):
   561         pattern = p
```

-->    562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
       563     else:
       564         pattern = None

```
    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    853 
    854     try:
```

-->      855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
        856     except Verbose:
        857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

```
  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
     414     while True:
     415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
```

-->      416                            not nested and not items))
         417         if not sourcematch("|"):
         418             break

```
    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
     614             if not item or (_len(item) == 1 and item[0][0] is AT):
     615                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
```

-->       616                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
         617             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
         618                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",

```
     error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Also, the regular expression can also be ^CLK or?CLK or any other regular 
   expression what is a generic solution to fix the issue when any string with 
    regular expression has been passed

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to delete the 'r' in the second line of the code below:

```
text = '*CLK*'
findtext = 'r'+text+".*"
colName = 'Signal'
```

It looks like youre trying to make a python raw string, if you are using python3 or greater thats not necessary.

Also the regex you are using is not suitable for what you want, try the following, you can try experimenting with https://pythex.org/ to construct the Regex you want. If all you are trying to do is match rows which contain CLK
    findtext = '.*CLK'

Comment: it is not working I am getting an error. Could you please try and tell me

Comment: If you get an error you need to post it so we can respond. Please try to remember that this is not a personal help desk.

Comment: How can we have a general solution of string contain any regular expression for example CLK? CLK* ^CLK

Answer (score 0):

remove the asterisks (*) and use the `.contains` method instead of the `.match` method. Use `case=False` to find upper and lowercase letters

see this code:

```
text = 'CLK'
findtext = 'r'+text+".*"
colName = 'Signal'

df[colName].str.contains(text, case=False)
```

Comment: but this text is passed a function argument so cannot remove * from that

Comment: use `text = text.strip("*")` to remove the *

Comment: I have edited the question and could please suggest a generic solution when the string is with a regular expression. For example?CLK , ^CLK

Comment: Any comment will help so generic solution any regular expression