# How to filter row with string with any regular expression in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup question for 
[how to filter rows based on unix based regular expressions passed as an input argument to a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454955/how-to-filter-rows-based-on-regular-expressions-passed-as-an-input-argument)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

csvFile = "csv.csv"
csvDelim = '@@@'
 df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, engine="python", index_col=False, delimiter=csvDelim )
df.head()


ID  col_1   
0   ACLKB
1   CLKAA
2   AACLK
3   BBBCLK
```

I have a python function find

```
 def find(self, findText, colName exactMatch):

      mask = (mask | (self.df[colName].astype('str') == findText))
```

Now the findText can *CLK* or?CLK or ^CLK or CLK$ etc. It can contain any regular expression. Now how to have a general solution where my find function can find a string with any regular expression

I am looking for really good documentation on how to support filter rows based on regex in pandas dataframe

Comment: It will be helpful if someone can answer this question